# Could not install Java 8 on my ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, java

Could not install Java 8 on my ubuntu server 18.04 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

How to install Java ?